# Debian - missing /by-uuid/ in boot image

Tags: linux, debian, grub

We proceeded few disk operations on our server (system disk was extended for new hard drives) and unfortunately after reboot boot stuck on error:

ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/c6ce1608-d59e-4072-8b8b-178d217ca849 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

If I try list this folder (by-uuid) then not exist. If I try create this folder and symbolic link inside manually, then server will start successfully, but just until next reboot. On next reboot again folder missing.

Can I ask you for help please?

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with the initramfs. You will have to fix it from a live session. Inside the live session, run these commands as root:

```
# Mount your Debian root drive
# Replace 'sdX' with the path to your Debian
# root
/dev/sdX /mnt

# Bind mount some virtual file systems
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

# chroot into your Debian root
chroot /mnt

# Update the initramfs
update-initramfs -u

# Refresh your grub config files
update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issues and the culprit was an old version of blkid. I was able to fix it be chrooting into my installation and running

```
apt-get install --reinstall util-linux
update-initramfs -u
```

A little more detailed for anyone curious update this issue:
On my system udev creates the by-uuid folder by running `blkid -o udev` (you can see this in `/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules`). The version of blkid I had did not support the udev format. Running `apt-get install util-linux` (which is the package that provides blkid) told the latest version was already installed, even though that was clearly not the case. After reinstalling util-linux my blkid binary was updated.